# Problema al incluir jQuery al HTML

Tags: javascript, html

el problema es simple pero no veo solucion, incluyo mi jQuery en mi HTML pero no lo reconoce.

html

```js
function prueba() {
 alert('alerta');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
 <button id="btn-1" onclick="prueba()">BTN</button>
</div>
<script src="/archivosprocesados.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

mi jerarquía de proyecto
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: en tu código no veo la etiqueta donde invocas a JQuery

Comment: incluyelo justo despues de la etique `<script src="/archivosprocesados.js"></script>` ahi llama a la librería `JQuery`

Comment: ese archivo no es jquery

Comment: fijate en este enlace asi es como se invoca a JQuery http://jsbin.com/xuweneguli/edit?html,output

Comment: me queda la duda por lo que veo, quieres incluir la librería jquery o quieres incluir un archivo externo de extensión js que tiene código que tu haz escrito?

Comment: ¿Hablas de la librería jQuery o del archivo llamado `archivosprocesados.js` o de ambas cosas? Para que nos entendamos: 1. Si la función `prueba()` se encuentra en  `archivosprocesados.js`, debes incluir el archivo antes de esta línea: `<button id="btn-1" onclick="prueba()">BTN</button>`, puede ser en el `head`; 2. Si `archivosprocesados.js` contiene código jQuery (esto no es lo mismo que Javascript, jQuery es sólo una librería), entonces debes incluir la librería jQuery antes de incluir a `archivosprocesados.js`

Comment: si, es asi, quiero incluir el arvhivo archivosprocesados.js, (que contendra codigo jquery, pero en este caso para fines de prueba contiene un JavaScript), la libreria Jquery es una "perzonalizada" que esta alojada en otra fuente, es por eso que no uso la libreria jQuery de google o alguna otra.

Comment: Pues lo mismo que te comenté más arriba, si dices que usas una librería jQuery personalizada, basta con que leas el punto 2 así: *2. Si `archivosprocesados.js` contiene código jQuery (esto no es lo mismo que Javascript, jQuery es sólo una librería), entonces debes incluir la librería* **[personalizada]** *jQuery* **[que has mencionado]** *antes de incluir a `archivosprocesados.js`*  ... pero debes asegurarte que esa librería personalizada funciona correctamente.

Answer (score 0):

El problema está en la ruta que pones en la linea

```
<script src="/archivosprocesados.js"></script>
```

ya que el símbolo `"/"` no indica el directorio actual. Prueba a poner el caracter `"."` delante. Quedaría así la línea:

```
<script src="./archivosprocesados.js"></script>
```